# CheckboxTreeViewer unchecked my selections after call refresh()

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I have filter on my `CheckboxTreeViewer` and before applying the filter on the treeviewer I checked an item. My filter is working on textbox and using `ModifyListener` function while writing.

```
text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        refreshFilter();
    }
});

private void refreshFilter() {
    myFilter.setFilter(text.getText());
    checkboxTreeViewer.refresh();
}
```

Filter is working perfect but after applying filter my older selections becomes unchecked. Maybe situation is about `LabelProvider` or `ContentProvider`.

I tried to call `checkboxTreeViewer.refresh(false);` not worked.

Also I've read about collapse problem by refresh. Suggestion is implement an `IElementComparer` and override `equals()` and `hashCode()` functions and maybe uncheck problem can be resolved with this way.

Here is my ContentProvider:

```
private class MyTreeContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return ((List) inputElement).toArray(new Object[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        if(parentElement instanceof FirstClass) {
            FirstClass is = (FirstClass)parentElement;
            return dbc.runJob(Util.byId(is.getId()).joinPrsl(true).joinIsltm(true)).getList().toArray(new SecondClass[0]);
        } else
            return new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {            
        if(element instanceof SecondClass)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

As conclusion, I can't solve my problem and I need your helps.

Comment: I think we need to see your content provider code.

Comment: @greg-449 I added my content provider code

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `getChildren` method returns new objects for a given parent element each time it is called.

In this case the `equals` method of the new object you create **must** return `true` when it is given the previous object representing the same value. The `hashCode` method must also return the same hash value.

Sometimes it can be problematic to change these methods. In this case you can create an `IElementComparer` class to provide special `equals` and `hashCode` methods for the tree. Call the viewer `setComparer` method to set the comparer for the tree.

Comment: How should I implement these methods also where? there are `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `ContentProvider` class and also there is `IElementComparer` while setting Comparer for treeViewer.

Comment: You implement them in the classes you return from `getChildren` and `getElements` - from the look of it `SecondClass` is one you need to do. Added something on IElementComparer to the answer.